# get unicode value from Querystring in proper format

Tags: java, jsp

I am a beginner in JSP programming and I would like to know which
code ( program ) I must write to get the Unicode value  from queryString

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Do you mean _codepoint_?

Answer (score 0):

For getting unicode value this code may help you.

> if(request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)
>    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

for more information see this :
[Click Here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1030399)

Answer (score 0):

The [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) returns an URL-encoded query string. You should rather prefer to use [`getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), [`getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) methods to retrieve respectively a single parameter, multiple parameters or the entire parameter map. Using those methods, the container will **automatically** URL-decode the parameter names and values for you. Inside a JSP those values are available by `${param.name}`, `${paramValues.name}` and `${pageContext.request.parameterMap}` respectively.

If you *really* insist in parsing and fiddling the raw query string yourself for some unobvious reason, then you have to split them on `&` and `=` to get the individual parameters and the name=value parts respectively and finally URL-decode each part yourself. Splitting can be done using [`String#split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and URL-decoding can be done using [`URLDecoder#decode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Here's a kickoff example:

```
String charset = request.getCharacterEncoding();
if (charset == null) charset = "UTF-8";
String queryString = request.getQueryString();

for (String parameter : queryString.split("&")) {
    String[] parts = parameter.split("=");
    String name = URLDecoder.decode(parts[0], charset);
    String value = URLDecoder.decode(parts[1], charset);
    // ...
}
```

The default charset should at least be the **same** as you've used to return the HTTP response. For example, when it's a JSP, it should be the same as you've specified in the `pageEncoding`:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```